# UILabel truncate tail not working with long word and multiple lines

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have several UILabels in tableCells or collectionViewItems set dynamically. Some texts are like this :

> Sometimesfirstwordverylong and some other words

The output is a text not autoshrinked like this :

```
Line 1 : Sometimesfirstwordverylo
Line 2 : ng and some other words
```

While **I would like the size to be autoshrinked** to be like :

```
Line 1 : Sometimesfirstwordverylong
Line 2 : and some other words
```

My settings :

```
constraints : leading, trailing, bottom, top
numberOfLines = 2
lineBreak = Truncate tail
Autoshrink = MinimumFontSize: 7
```

I tried many other settings without any success.

I also tried the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059631/autoshrink-on-a-uilabel-with-multiple-lines?noredirect=1&lq=1) without any luck.

Comment: Try reducing the `MinimumFontSize` more and see how text in label shows.

Comment: @Amit thank you for the answer. Unfortunately that's something I have already tried without any success. The label stays exactly the same :(

Comment: This post has a `UILabel` extension that works in my quick testing. Note that it needs to be called after the label has been fully instantiated, so I put it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, and I added a `guard self.bounds.width > 0` at the beginning to avoid unnecessary passes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121240/ios-uilabel-autoshrink-so-word-doesnt-truncate-to-two-lines

Comment: yes ! Many thanks @DonMag ! It works like a charm !