# Xcode IB - UILabel multiline text wrapping issue iPhone X + newer models

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am building an app that displays a label in the center of the screen and the text changes depending on which cell the user selected in a separate table view. Up until now I had been testing mostly on my iPhone 7 Plus and older devices, but now that I have an iPhone Xs, I'm discovering an annoying text wrapping issue. Here are my IB settings for the UILabel:

[image]

The UILabel should have 3 available lines to work with. The default font size is 150 but the text should be able to shrink down to size 15 given the minimum font scale I have set up. The vast majority of the selectable text inputs work as intended and the text scales and line breaks appropriately to display on 1, 2, or 3 lines. There are a couple of text options that cut off in the middle of a word, like so (In this example, the text should take up 2 lines, breaking at the space between the 'n' and the '2'):

[image]

The annoying part is that this text wrapping issue ONLY happens on the iPhone X or newer models. Any phone from the 8 Plus or older has no problems displaying correctly. I tried messing around with the constraints (the sides of the label are inset 20 points from the safe area and the top/bottom are attached to UIViews above and below), but nothing has been successful so far.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit**: Adjusting the height of the label (lessening it) seems to allow the text to display correctly, but I would prefer to keep the height as it is if I can. I'm still confused as to why the text doesn't auto-shrink correctly and break the line at the space.

Comment: If you need consistent solution regarding those 3 lines then you need static frame for the label. While iPhoneX is kinda large and your label most probably is dynamic then is it made with 2 lines for X series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: [iOS UILabel autoshrink so word doesn't truncate to two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121240/ios-uilabel-autoshrink-so-word-doesnt-truncate-to-two-lines/47469960)

Essentially, the function determines the length of the longest word in the string and resizes the font to accommodate that word. The only other thing I needed to address was to reset the font size to the original size before calling the function so that strings with shorter words would be adjusted down from the original size instead of using the font size of the previously adjusted string.