# how to fix the wrong word wrap?

Tags: swift

for a very long time I can’t solve a simple problem, namely: transferring a word to a new line and automatically reducing the label if the word does not fit. Tell me how to be in this situation.

```
@IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var transcriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var translationLabel: UILabel!


var index = 0
var word = ""
var transcription = ""
var translation = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    wordLabel.text = word
    transcriptionLabel.text = ""
    translationLabel.text = ""

    wordLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    wordLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1

    transcriptionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    transcriptionLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1

    translationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    translationLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1

    self.transcriptionLabel.alpha = 0.0
    self.translationLabel.alpha = 0.0
}
```

[image: runApp]
[image: storyboard]
[image: storyboard]

Comment: just to be clear, you do not want the text to wrap, but just to shrink.. am i correct ?

Comment: @humblePilgrimI need the text to be not in 1 line, but in several, and the transfer is carried out by the full word. if necessary, decrease the font

Comment: Please look at the following post .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121240/ios-uilabel-autoshrink-so-word-doesnt-truncate-to-two-lines

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [humblePilgrim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419261/humblepilgrim), for the suggested answer, it really helped. I leave the link to the source and attach the answer itself.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121240/ios-uilabel-autoshrink-so-word-doesnt-truncate-to-two-lines)

> Swift 4.2

```
extension UILabel {
// Adjusts the font size to avoid long word to be wrapped
func fitToAvoidWordWrapping() {
    guard adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth else {
        return // Adjust font only if width fit is needed
    }
    guard let words = text?.components(separatedBy: " ") else {
        return // Get array of words separate by spaces
    }

    // I will need to find the largest word and its width in points
    var largestWord: NSString = ""
    var largestWordWidth: CGFloat = 0

    // Iterate over the words to find the largest one
    for word in words {
        // Get the width of the word given the actual font of the label
        let wordWidth = word.size(withAttributes: [.font: font]).width

        // check if this word is the largest one
        if wordWidth > largestWordWidth {
            largestWordWidth = wordWidth
            largestWord = word as NSString
        }
    }

    // Now that I have the largest word, reduce the label's font size until it fits
    while largestWordWidth > bounds.width && font.pointSize > 1 {
        // Reduce font and update largest word's width
        font = font.withSize(font.pointSize - 1)
        largestWordWidth = largestWord.size(withAttributes: [.font: font]).width
    }
}
}
```

I thank user [Dam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1511646/dam) for the answer.